# What is the motivation of multipartite secret sharing?

Tags: secret-sharing, reference-request

In this [thesis](https://upcommons.upc.edu/bitstream/handle/2117/94536/TOFV1de1.pdf?sequence=1&isAllowed=y) chapter 3.1

> A multipartite secret sharing scheme is a scheme in which the set of
> participants is divided into several parts and all participants in the
> same part play an equivalent role in the scheme.
>
> Secret sharing schemes for multipartite access structures have
> received considerable attention. **This is due to the fact that
> multipartite secret sharing schemes can be seen as a natural
> generalization of threshold secret sharing schemes.** While in threshold
> secret sharing schemes all the participants are equivalent, **in a
> multipartite secret sharing scheme the participants are distributed
> into different classes in which all the participants are equivalent**.
> In addition, similarly to threshold access structures, multipartite
> access structures can be described in a very **compact way**, by means of
> a few conditions that are independent of the total number of
> participants

Is the above paragraph (information) sufficient for the motivation of multipartite secret sharing scheme?

If it is not sufficient information for the motivation of multipartite secret sharing scheme, please suggest where I have to read motivation of multipartite secret sharing scheme.